# Non-string symbolic languages (e.g. diagrams) as "formal languages"

Tags: logic, category-theory, formal-languages, meta-math

A formal language is a concept that is fundamental to computer science, logic, and metamathematics. It is defined as a **subset $\mathcal L$ of the set $S^*$ of  *sequences of symbols* from a set $S$, that can be generated by certain formal production rules**.

The notion of formal language can be used to formalize certain notions mathematicians often think about somewhat informally/intuitively, the prime example being proofs.

However, there are symbolic languages that are not "strings of symbols", perhaps a prime example being categorical diagrams, e.g.:

[image]

While we can represent this diagram as a string (i.e. write a string that describes an algorithm to *construct* the diagram), **the diagram doesn't naturally have the structure of a string**.

**My question is basically, Can we think of non-string languages like this as "formal languages"**, in the sense that we can treat them with the same degree of rigor as e.g. a proof calculus on first-order propositions (i.e. strings)? I have always thought of non-string languages like this as "relatively" more informal objects than the fully rigorous first-order logics to which we can apply automated theorem provers.

Comment: It seems to me that it becomes a formal language if you are able to give a set of rules that describe all the valid diagrams of the language. The other question is unclear. What does "treat with the same degree of rigor" mean? Another question is what you want to do with the language.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, this can be done. At its core, a deductive system *(ignoring semantics for the moment)* is a set of things called sentences together with a deduction relation on that set; there's no requirement that the sentences be strings or that the deduction relation be "generated by" operations on strings, and a deductive system based around (say) diagrams is perfectly possible.

For one example of such a thing, Hughes has presented an entirely *graph-theoretic* approach to classical [propositional logic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408282.pdf) and [first-order logic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.11236.pdf) - neither sentences nor proofs are strings. They also aren't simply graphs, though, so this may not quite be what you're looking for, but I think it's still valuable to consider. In particular it illustrates the broader point that **as long as we define things precisely**, the components of our deductive system can be whatever we want.

(*Implementing* non-string-based deductive systems on a computer is of course a whole other issue, but that's a side point.)